# AVL Tree for Java

Tags: java, binary-tree, nodes, treenode, avl-tree

I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly as this is my very first time coding with nodes. But here's my code so far, if someone can look over it and help me out with understanding if I'm doing anything wrong. Also my insert/remove methods are giving me a hard time. The professor gave us the pseudocode for that but I can't seem to grasp how to interpret it into Java code as I've never done this type of code before. Mostly because there's a if statement that checks the heights to see if the tree is balanced, how would i implement height in this? Hints or any help is greatly appreciated, I've been stuck on this for a while. Thanks!

I also don't think I did my constructor correctly and I'm unsure about it. The return in insert/remove can be ignored, it was just put in there to make sure the rest of the code will compile.

```
public class AvlNode{

    public static void main(String[]args){

    }
    //constructor
    public class AvlTreeNode{
        private int num;
        private AvlTreeNode left;
        private AvlTreeNode right;

        public AvlTreeNode left(){
            return this.left;
        }

        public AvlTreeNode right(){
            return this.right;
        }

        public int value(){
            return this.num;
        }
    }
    //method to find the number specified on the node
    public AvlTreeNode find(AvlTreeNode t, int x){
        if(t == null){
            return null;
        }
        if( t.value() == x){
            return t;
        }
        else if(x < t.value()){
            return find(t.left(), x);
        }
        else{
            return find(t.right(), x);
        }
    }
    //method to insert a new node and number to a tree
    public AvlTreeNode insert(AvlTreeNode t, int x){
        if(t == null){
            t = new AvlTreeNode(x, null, null);
            return t;
        }
        if(x < t.value()){
            t.left = insert(t.left(), x);
        }
        return t;
    }
    //method to remove a node and number from the tree
    public AvlTreeNode remove(AvlTreeNode t, int x){
        return t;
    }
    //Inorder traversal method, should print out numbers in ascending order if correct
    public void inOrder(AvlTreeNode t){
        if(t != null){
            inOrder(t.left());
            System.out.print(t.value() + " ");
            inOrder(t.right());
        }
    }
    //single rotation of nodes to balance tree, rotating leftwards
    public static AvlTreeNode singleRotateWithLeft( AvlTreeNode k1){
        AvlTreeNode k2 = k1.left;
        k1.left = k2.right;
        k2.right = k1;
        return k2;
    }
    //single rotation of nodes to balance tree, rotating rightwards
    public static AvlTreeNode singleRotateWithRight( AvlTreeNode k2){
        AvlTreeNode k1 = k2.right;
        k2.right = k1.left;
        k1.left = k2;
        return k1;
    }
    //double rotation of nodes towards the left
    public static AvlTreeNode doubleRotateWithLeft( AvlTreeNode k3){
        k3.left = doubleRotateWithRight(k3.left);
        return doubleRotateWithLeft(k3);
    }
    //double rotation of nodes towards the right
    public static AvlTreeNode doubleRotateWithRight( AvlTreeNode k2){
        k2.right = doubleRotateWithLeft(k2.right);
        return doubleRotateWithRight(k2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the constructor: I think the thing that is wrong, is that you mistake the inner class you use to describe a AvlTreeNode for a constructor. In all probability, you don't need to write an explicit constructor, because the default (empty) one will do for you.

The construction of a Tree can be viewed as the insertion of all its nodes to an empty tree.

Regarding the height, you should probably view the height of a tree as a property of each AvlTreeNode (so, next to `num` you need a `height` variable). The next thing will be to implement insert and remove so that the correct local transformations / rotations are used and so that the heights of the inserted node and its children are increased or decreased appropriately.

edit: I now see that your code uses a constructor with three arguments. You can use a constructor like the one in this example code.

```
//inner class for the node
public class AvlTreeNode{
    private int num;
    private int height;

    private AvlTreeNode left;
    private AvlTreeNode right;

    //this is the constructor!
    public AvlTreeNode(int value, AvlTreeNode left, AvlTreeNode right){
        this.num = value;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        this.height = 1;

        if (left != null && left.height() >= height){
            height = left.height() + 1;
        }
        if (right != null && right.height() >= height){
            height = right.height() + 1;
        }
    }

    public AvlTreeNode left(){
        return this.left;
    }

    public AvlTreeNode right(){
        return this.right;
    }

    public int value(){
        return this.num;
    }

    public int height(){
        return height;
    }
}
```

Comment: So just to be sure I'm understanding this, you're saying I could just make that empty class of AvlTreeNode as a constructor with only the variables in there? That's something I'm also not very good or understand fully is constructors.

I have the insert/remove pseudocode but just need to figure out how to implement it into java code.



So in the insert method, I could just use t.left = insert(t.left, x) instead of using t.left()?

Comment: I should also mention there's the "return t = new AvlTreeNode(x,null,null)" under the insert method, wouldn't I need an explicit method in the constructor for that?

Comment: Ahh, I missed that code. Yes, probably you need a constructor that will set the num to the first argument, and sets the left and right trees as the second and third arguments.

Comment: Also, in that constructor you can calculate the height value basef I'm the heights of the subtrees.

Comment: please refer to the edit of my answer: I've added a sample constructor to your inner class.