# how to find the height of right child minus height of the left child in a tree

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree, avl-tree

i have this class in java for Nodes of a tree

```
public class Node {

Node (int v, Node lt, Node rt){
    value = v;
    left = lt;
    right = rt;
    height = 0;
    parent = null;
}

Node (int v){
    this (v, null, null);
}

int value;
int height;
Node left;
Node right;
Node parent;
}
```

height of this node is (this.right.height - this.left.height)

and height of a node which has just 1 child and it's child is leaf is 1 if child is right child and -1 if child is left child for the node

how can i do this??

(i want to write an avl tree)

Comment: [AVL-Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL-tree) have the restriction that the left and right side are only allowed to differ in height by a factor of 1. You might have a look at [this implementation here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19481815/avl-tree-for-java) although it is not accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below one

```
public int height(Node root){
       if(root == null)return 0;
       return 1+Max(height(root.left),height(root.right));
    }

    heightDifference = (height(this.right) - height(this.left))
```